# How IBM Workload 9.3.3 installation process construct the JDBC URL to connect to a Oracle database?

Tags: workload-scheduler

Installing or upgrading to IBM Workload 9.3.3 with an Oracle database, using both the Installation Manager silent method or the  wizard, in order to enstabilsh a JDBC connection to the database, you have to specify  the values of the following properties:

- Database hostname
- Database port
- Oracle net service name

In order to fulfill correctly these values, especially in a complex environment with Multiple Local Listeners, Multiple Database Nodes/SIDS, would be useful to know how the JDBC URL is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

The IBM Workload 9.3.3 installation process uses the JDBC driver type 4 and the Thin-style service name syntax to construct the JDBC URL string to connect to the Oracle Database. The syntax is:

“jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/OracleNetServiceName”

Answer (score 0):

Always use the long form of the connection URL as shown here. Refer to [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionManagementSamples/DataSourceSample.java) on Github

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))